# SHA-1 shows different output in UTF-8 Java

Tags: java, php, utf-8, sha1

I have created a Sha1 function that works in most times the same way as PHP's sha1 function, and gives the same output. But when UTF-8 characters appear, they differ. For example, with the string "hj6¬", in PHP I get "7f9d591232c5fde9f757c4d8472921517991dc3c" while in my Java function I get "c963b7df20488e9ef50c1a309c1fa747ab5d8822". Here is the Java function:

https://github.com/Razican/Java-Utils/blob/master/src/razican/utils/StringUtils.java#L115

Which one is the correct one? How can I implement it in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct output is **7f9d591232c5fde9f757c4d8472921517991dc3c**. You are dropping a byte:

```
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(str.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, str.length());
        sha1hash = md.digest();
```

The above code assumes that the length of the UTF-16 string equals the length of the UTF-8 encoded byte array. If the the UTF-8 form is longer than the UTF-16 form the digest will be incorrect.

```
codepoint   glyph   escaped    UTF-8           info
=======================================================================
U+0068      h       \u0068     68,             BASIC_LATIN, LOWERCASE_LETTER
U+006a      j       \u006a     6a,             BASIC_LATIN, LOWERCASE_LETTER
U+0036      6       \u0036     36,             BASIC_LATIN, DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER
U+00ac      ¬       \u00ac     c2,ac,          LATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT, MATH_SYMBOL
```

Using the length of the array:

```
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        md.update(utf8, 0, utf8.length);
```

*You could also use `md.update(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`*

Comment: Thank you! That almost solved all my issue, but I have one problem left, the thing is that I have a method that instead of working with Strings works with char arrays. I have the same issue as above: https://github.com/Razican/Java-Utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/razican/utils/StringUtils.java#L147 But don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Consider using `ByteBuffer buf = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(charArray)); byte[] utf8 = new byte[buf.limit()]; buf.get(utf8); md.update(utf8);`